# return vector of objects to a function

Tags: c++, function, class, vector

What is the correct syntax to do this? Surely I made some stupid mistake ... unfortunately I'm trying to better understand the vectors. I know that I created an unnecessary pointer, but I need to understand the syntax.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class otherClass
{
    public:
        otherClass(int x):value(x)
        {
            //ctor
        }
        int getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }
    private:
        int value;
};

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(int x)
        {
            obj = new std::vector<otherClass>(x,otherClass{5});
        }
        otherClass getVector()
        {
            return obj; //HERE FIRST ERROR <---------------
        }
    private:
        std::vector<otherClass>*obj;
};

void doSomething(otherClass*obj)
{
    std::cout << obj->getValue() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass*aClass = new MyClass(10);
    doSomething(aClass->getVector()); //HERE SECOND ERROR <---------------
    return 0;
}
```

Errors that I get when compiling:

First:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'std::vector<otherClass>*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
```

Second:

```
error: cannot convert 'otherClass' to 'otherClass*' for argument '1' to 'void doSomething(otherClass*)'
```

Comment: `getVector` sounds like it should return a vector, not an `otherClass`.

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to do. You want to return a vector from a function?

Comment: This program can be simplified to `std::cout << 5 << std::endl;`

Comment: A quick reminder: In C++ objects don't need to be allocated dynamically with `new`. It is most often better not to and let the object's lifespan be controlled by scope.

Comment: @myaut Inappropriate comment ... this code is a summary of the passage that I must do. in my program all this has a purpose.

Comment: @user4581301 you could rewrite the code with an example that allows me to do what I want (also using pointers) as an answer?

Comment: @aschepler you could rewrite the code with an example that allows me to do what I want (also using pointers) as an answer? If I asked for help there will be a reason... I'm sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: I am sorry, friend, but I am unable to infer your needs from your code. Perhaps add a text description of your goal to your question.

Comment: @user4581301 I made a very simple code, but unfortunately I see that I have not explained well enough. I'll ask again tomorrow, the post will be suspended, although I do not think it's right, the problem is written in the title too.

Comment: Your code is confused, but I think it can benefit with careful use of a typedef.   Consider "typedef  std::vector<otherClass>  otherClassVec_t".  Now you use a pointer or refernce (to this new type) where you wish to provide access or return a vector.  (i.e. otherClassVec_t*  or  otherClassVec_t& ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no point in using any pointer here. None!

Second, your getters should be qualified `const`, and return const references for heavy objects like your vector. It prevents an useless copy.

```
int getValue() const 
//             ^^^^^ 
{
    return value;
}
```

within `otherClass`, and

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int x) : obj(x, otherClass{5}) // construction here
    { }
    std::vector<otherClass> const & getVector() const
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^
    {
        return obj;
    }
private:
    std::vector<otherClass> obj; // no pointer, just a vector
};
```

Then in the main:

```
MyClass aClass(10);
```

What you want to do with `doSomething()` is unclear. With your code `doSomething(aClass->getVector())` you're supposed to handle the returned vector of `otherClass`es. So it should be:

```
void doSomething(std::vector<otherClass> const & obj)
```

I let you write its code.

Comment: But in my program "obj" is a pointer, because then I need to destroy it with "delete". "aClass" is a pointer for the same reason...

Comment: @nostyn It should not be. There's no reason for that.

Comment: So if I wanted to do it using pointers could I not? Why? I can not pass the obj address to the function and avoid needlessly allocate more memory?

Comment: @nostyn You're free to write ugly bad code. But I won't help you do that ;) And there is no unnecessary allocation in my code. Just one vector thanks to the reference.

Comment: I did not want to do it :/ but I wanted to know the syntax. In any case, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

just say what you want to return

```
std::vector<otherClass> *getVector()
{
    return obj;
}
```

or

```
std::vector<otherClass> getVector()
{
    return *obj;
}
```

Comment: Also sad not to return a const reference in the second case.

Comment: i am just trying to get the OP moving a bit, obviously there are many many things wrong with the provided code

Comment: I asked for a correct syntax, I am sure there are mistakes ... desolate.